# Move QGraphicsItem with mouse hover

Tags: qt, draggable

I'm trying to move a `QGraphicsItem` with the mouse hover over the parent item.

```
BaseItem::BaseItem(const QRectF &bounds) 
    : theBounds(bounds), theMousePressed(false) 
{
   theLineItem = new LineItem(theBounds, this);
    setAcceptHoverEvents(true); 
}
```

and

```
void BaseItem::hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event) 
{
    QPointF position =  mapToScene( event->pos());
    theLineItem->setPos( position); 
}
```

But the item is not moving. Is there any other way to move the item on the scene with mouse move, without using the `ItemIsMovable` flag, because I want the item to be moved around the parent item, once it's invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the LineItem, in its constructor you pass the BaseItem as the parent.

A call to setPos on a GraphicsItem, sets the position of the item relative to its parent which, in this case, is the BaseItem.

Mapping the event->pos() to scene coordinates is wrong here. event->pos() returns the position in local coordinates of the receiving object, which in this case is the BaseItem.

Therefore, you should be setting the position of theLineItem directly with event->pos().

```
theLineItem->setPos(event->pos());
```

Note that if you did happen to want the event position in scene coordinates, there's a function already available: -

```
event->scenePos();
```

So you would not have needed to call mapToScene.